# Dynamically choose a chart measure in Power BI

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-powerbi

I have a number of charts within a single dashboard in Power BI, as well as a number of measures that I want to examine individually within this dashboard - hopefully by cycling through them.

Instead of creating separate pages/dashes for each measure, I would like to dynamically populate each chart with a chosen measure most likely accessed via a filter.

I know something like this can be done in Tableau, (http://breaking-bi.blogspot.com/2013/02/dynamically-choose-fields-displayed-on.html), but can this replicated in Power BI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the disconnected Measure table and a SWITCH ( TRUE ... ) function.

There's a good explanation of this technique on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213984

In Power BI you can use Enter Data to create your Measure table.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip on using StackOverflow for Power BI questions and on the link. It worked a treat! Will leave my question and your answer up on SuperUser unless you suggest otherwise (delete here and repost on StackOverflow)